# проблема с VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

при использовании VSCode не печатается английская буква T не нажимается и выдает ошибку, уже удалялись все плагины и не однократно переустанавливалась программа. Что делать подскажите.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Какую именно ошибку?

Comment: Может это связанно с сочетанием клавиш `Ctrl + T` - которая показывает все символы?