# Проблема с VSCode не печатается символ

Tags: visual-studio-code

при написании кода в программе VSCode на абсолютно всех языках не печатается символ T. Не раз переустанавливал программу и удалял все плагины при написании символа Т программа выдает ошибку "такой команды нет или не могу выполнить команду" на Т у меня ничего не установлено.

Comment: Добавьте скриншот. Я предполагаю, что там написано, какой именно команды нет, из этого возможно получится понять в чем именно проблема. Ну и по сути это дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1399075/1365 . Не пробовали дополнять вопросы (под вопросом есть ссылка "править") вместо удаления учетки и создание нового вопроса под новой учеткой?

Comment: стоит ли vim emulation for Visual studio code, если стоит, то удалите